# Invalid hook call error when wrapping MuiThemeProvider within App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

I get the following error when I wrap MuiThemeProvider in App.js. The page will not load at all. I've used it similarly in other projects, so not sure why this is happening.

> react.development.js:1476 Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

App.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import Home from './views/Home'
import ProjectDetailsForm from './components/ProjectDetailsForm/ProjectDetailsForm'
import { MuiThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles'
import theme from './styles/theme'

function App() {
  return (
    <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Router>
        <div className="app">
          <Routes>
            <Route
              path="/"
              element={[
                <Home key="1"></Home>,
                <ProjectDetailsForm key="2"></ProjectDetailsForm>
              ]}></Route>
          </Routes>
        </div>
      </Router>
    </MuiThemeProvider>
  )
}

export default App
```

theme.js

```
// import { common } from '@material-ui/core/colors'
import { createTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles'
// import { black } from '@mui/material/colors'

const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiFormLabel: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          color: '#000'
        }
      }
    },
    MuiInputLabel: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          color: '#000'
        }
      }
    }
  }
})

export default theme
```

Comment: I think this might be an issue with how MUI is playing with react v18 (assuming your using v 18). [Looks like support is a WIP](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/29844). You could try downgrading to previous react version for now.

Answer (score 0):

This issue can happen when you're React tries to load twice. For example, if I make my own library that uses React, and then import it locally into a project that also uses React. What's in this file `./components/ProjectDetailsForm/ProjectDetailsForm'`?

Answer (score 0):

**Solved:**

I realized I hadn't yet installed `@material-ui/core`. Once I tried, I was getting 'could not resolve dependency errors'. Had to use legacy MUI dependencies due to conflicts with React 18.

[Found the fix here](https://namespaceit.com/blog/mui-installation-doesnt-work-with-react-18)